# Increases the length of a column in hbm file of hibernate

Tags: hibernate, size, hbm

I have to increase the size of a email body column in hbm file.
This Column shows warning

> Data too long for column 'EMAILBODYCONTENT'

Comment: Please update your question with the hibernate config and Java Class.

Answer (score 0):

what i did is, i increased the 'length' of that column in hbm.xml file. Now it accepts.